# Topic modeling for grouped data

Tags: topic-models

Is there a variation of Latent Dirichlet Allocation (LDA) for grouped data? As an example, let us consider corpus of all Yahoo Q&A (where for simplicity we consider a question lumped together with all the corresponding answers as a document). While submitting a question to Yahoo's site, user has to specify a category to which it belongs to (let us, again for simplicity assume that categories are simple, instead of hierarchical). Is there a version of LDA that takes advantage of this information?

Comment: LDA means linear discriminant analysis to many people here. Important to spell out what you mean. Locally famous terminology is not necessarily globally familiar.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at *Labeled LDA*.

[Ramage et al.: Labeled LDA: A supervised topic model for credit attribution in multi-labeled corpora](https://aclweb.org/anthology/D/D09/D09-1026.pdf)

there is even an [implementation](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tmt/tmt-0.4/) available